# Como parar Blucles en XSTL

Tags: bucles, xslt

Estoy intentando crear un pdf con xsl y hay un problema que no consigo resolver.
En mí estructura hay 3 tipos de elementos (CLDIAGREAL, CLRESULTAD, CLINTERVEN). CLRESULTAD y CLINTERVEN son hijos de un CLDIAGREAL, si los tiene. La estructura ya viene ordenada CLDIAGREAL y sus hijos debajo.
Mí intención es formatearlo en un pdf de forma:

- CLDIAGREAL
  - CLRESULTAD....CLRESULTAD
  - CLINTERVEN....CLINTERVEN
- CLDIAGREAL
  - CLRESULTAD....CLRESULTAD
  - CLINTERVEN....CLINTERVEN

Estructura:
-

Diagnósticos activos

Configure el nuevo elemento.

```
-<Table>
-<Header>
<ColumnHeader>CLASE</ColumnHeader>
<ColumnHeader>NOMBRE</ColumnHeader>
</Header>
-<Body>
-<Row>
<Column>CLDIAGREAL</Column>
<Column>Absceso</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLDIAGREAL</Column>
<Column>Ansiedad</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLRESULTAD</Column>
<Column>Nivel de ansiedad</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLINTERVEN</Column>
<Column>Disminución de la ansiedad</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLDIAGREAL</Column>
<Column>Abrasión cutánea</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLDIAGREAL</Column>
<Column>Convulsiones</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLDIAGREAL</Column>
<Column>Conocimientos deficientes</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLRESULTAD</Column>
<Column>Conocimiento: Regimen terapéutico</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLINTERVEN</Column>
<Column>Enseñanza: Actividades/ejercicio prescrito</Column>
</Row>
<Column>CLRESULTAD</Column>
<Column>Conducta de prevención de caídas</Column>
</Row>
-<Row>
<Column>CLINTERVEN</Column>
<Column>Prevención de caídas</Column>
</Row>
</Body>
</Table>
</Tag>
```

He intentado recorrer todas las row con un for-each pero no puedo interumpirlo y salirme de la iteración cuando tengo que cambiar de elemento para hacer una nueva fila en el pdf. Tampoco puedo hacer varios for-each porque me sacaría todos los elementos CLRESULTAD y CLINTERVEN y no es lo que espero, sólo pueden juntos salir los que son hijos del elemento CLDIAGREAL superior.

También lo he intentado con una template recursiva pero a la hora de pasar los parametros no los toma correctamente.

La primera template coge el primer elemento que siempre va a ser CLDIAGREAL, lo pinta, después hace la llamada recursiva a esta primera template y evalúa la siguiente row, si es un elemento  CLRESULTAD. Si es así llama a otra template que pinta el CLRESULTAD y evalúa mediante el indice si el siguiente elemento es CLRESULTAD. Si es CLRESULTAD hace llamada recursiva a esta misma template. Pero si es CLINTERVEN debe hacer un cambio de fila. El problema es que al llamar a la primera template no está asignando los parámetros.

Gracias de antemano por vuestro tiempo, si os ocurre algo, soy todo "oidos"...

Pegaría las Template pero son algo extensas y no sé como quedaría.

```
<xsl:template name="TablaPlan">
        <xsl:param name="titulos"/>
        <xsl:param name="contador"/>
        <xsl:param name="indice"/>
        <xsl:param name="salta"/>
        
        <xsl:variable name="elemento" select="//Tags/Tag[14]/Table/Body/Row[$indice+$salta]"/>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="sans-serif" margin-left="9pt">
                    <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed" >
                    <xsl:if test="$indice = 1">
                        <fo:table-header>
                            <!-- Fila del titulo -->
                            <fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always" background-color="#FFFFFF">
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="4">
                                    <fo:block text-align="left" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" margin-left="10pt" >
                                        <fo:inline font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" font-size="10pt">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$titulos"/>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-header>
                    </xsl:if>
                        <fo:table-column/>
                        <fo:table-body border-width="0.1px" border-style="none">
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <fo:table width="100%">
                                            <fo:table-column/>
                                                <fo:table-body>
                                                 <xsl:if test="normalize-space($elemento/Column[1]) = 'CLDIAGREAL' or normalize-space($elemento/Column[1]) = 'CLDIAGRIES'">
                                                    <fo:table-row keep-together="always" font-weight="bold">                                                    
                                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" border-style="none" margin-left="30pt" border-left-style="none">
                                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                                <fo:inline font-size="9pt">
                                                                    <xsl:text>&#x2022;</xsl:text>
                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                                <fo:inline font-size="9pt">
                                                                    <xsl:value-of select="$elemento/Column[2]"/>                                                                    
                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </fo:table-row>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="normalize-space($elemento/Column[1]) = 'CLRESULTAD'">
                                                    <fo:table-row keep-together="always" >                                                  
                                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" border-style="none" margin-left="60pt" border-left-style="none">
                                                            <fo:block text-align="left">                                                            
                                                            <xsl:call-template name="pintaElemento">
                                                                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$indice" />
                                                                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$contador" />
                                                                <xsl:with-param name="clase" select="$elemento/Column[1]" />
                                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </fo:table-row>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="normalize-space($elemento/Column[1]) = 'CLINTERVEN'">
                                                    <fo:table-row keep-together="always" >                                                  
                                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" border-style="none" margin-left="60pt" border-left-style="none">
                                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                                <fo:inline font-size="9pt">
                                                                    <xsl:value-of select="$elemento/Column[2]"/>                                                                    
                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </fo:table-row>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                </fo:table-body>
                                            </fo:table>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                    <!--fin estructura de tabla-->
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        
        <xsl:variable name="next" select="$contador - 1" />
        <xsl:variable name="siguiente" select="$indice + 1" />
        <xsl:if test="$next > 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="TablaPlan">
                <xsl:with-param name="titulos" select="$titulos" />
                <xsl:with-param name="contador" select="$next" />               
                <xsl:with-param name="indice" select="$siguiente" />
                <xsl:with-param name="salta" select="0" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template name="pintaElemento">
        <xsl:param name="index"/>
        <xsl:param name="count"/>
        <xsl:param name="clase"/>
        <xsl:variable name="resultados" select="//Tags/Tag[14]/Table/Body/Row[$index]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="siguiente" select="//Tags/Tag[14]/Table/Body/Row[$index+1]/Column[1]"/>                 
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space($clase) = normalize-space($siguiente)">
                        <xsl:variable name="next" select="$count - 1" />
                        <xsl:variable name="i" select="$index + 1" />
                        <xsl:if test="$next > 0 ">
                            <xsl:call-template name="pintaElemento">
                                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$i" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$next" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="clase" select="$siguiente" />                         
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>                 
                        <xsl:variable name="n" select="$count - 1" />
                        <xsl:variable name="it" select="$index + 1" />  
                        <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
                            <xsl:call-template name="exit">
                                <xsl:with-param name="titulos" select="'Hola'" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$n" />             
                                <xsl:with-param name="indice" select="$it" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:otherwise>    
                </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="exit">
        <xsl:param name="titulos"/>
        <xsl:param name="count"/>
        <xsl:param name="indice"/>
                    <fo:table width="100%" >
                    <fo:table-body border-width="0.1px" border-style="solid">
                    
                        <xsl:call-template name="TablaPlan">
                            <xsl:with-param name="titulos" select="$titulos" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />             
                            <xsl:with-param name="indice" select="$indice" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="salta" select="1" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```